Sonarqube - Error Refactor this function to reduce its Cognitive Complexity from 18 to the 15 allowed - in javascript
I am getting this error :
30:9   error    Refactor this function to reduce its Cognitive Complexity from 18 to the 15 allowed
Possible solutions I tried is like using if and then else if for the rest of the conditions.
Error will go but my code will not work as expected
How can I refactor the below code?
 workItemDetails.value.map((e: any) => {
        const existingData = touchPointRequests.filter((t) => +t.ticket_no === e.id);
        if (existingData.length && e.fields['System.State']) {
          this.updateBrandWebsiteState(existingData, e.fields['System.State']);
        }
        const existingGoLiveDate = new Date(new Date(existingData[0].go_live_date).toDateString());
        const newGoLiveDate = new Date(new Date(e.fields['Custom.GoLiveDate']).toDateString());
        const updateData: any = {};
        if (
          existingData.length &&
          e.fields['Custom.GoLiveDate'] &&
          newGoLiveDate.getTime() !== existingGoLiveDate.getTime()
        ) {
          const zonedDate = utcToZonedTime(new Date(e.fields['Custom.GoLiveDate']), 'Europe/Berlin');
          updateData.goLiveDate = zonedDate;
        }
        if (
          existingData.length &&
          e.fields['Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Priority'] &&
          AzurePriority[e.fields['Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Priority']] !== existingData[0].priority
        ) {
          updateData.priority = AzurePriority[e.fields['Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Priority']];
        }

        if (Object.keys(updateData).length) {
          this.touchPointRequestRepository.UpdateTouchPointRequestById(existingData[0].tpr_id, updateData);
        }
        if (
          existingData.length &&
          e.fields['Custom.PreviewLinks'] != undefined &&
          existingData[0].preview_link !== e.fields['Custom.PreviewLinks']
        ) {
          this.brandWebsiteRequestRepository.UpdateBrandWebsiteRequestByTPId(existingData[0].tpr_id, {
            previewLink: e.fields['Custom.PreviewLinks'],
          });
          this.sendPreviewLinkUpdateMail(existingData);
        }

        if (
          existingData.length &&
          e.fields['System.State'] === 'In Review' &&
          e.fields['Custom.PreviewLinks'] != undefined &&
          existingData[0].feedback_and_comments !== e.fields['Custom.PreviewLinks']
        ) {
          this.brandWebsiteRequestRepository.UpdateBrandWebsiteRequestByTPId(existingData[0].tpr_id, {
            feedbackAndComments: e.fields['Custom.PreviewLinks'],
          });
        }
      });


Pretty much all your conditions start with existingData.length. You can split it into two functions where one would handle only for empty existing data and the other for non empty existing data.

@JakubKotrs  Can you please show like how?
